# how to discard the first 4 RTP bytes on wireshark captures?

Tags: wireshark, rtp, h.323

When capturing H460 data on wireshark (on multiplexed mode), wireshark does not parse RTP data correctly. it should discard first 4 bytes on any RTP packet. looking for hints how to do that

Thanks
  Amit

Comment: Could you explain which bytes should be removed by Wireshark with reference to the RTP header? Do you mean that there are 4 bytes that precede the RTP header in the UDP payload.http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/rtp.htm

Comment: The 4 bytes that preceed the header need to be removed. After that the regular RTP header follows.

Comment: This RTP multiplexing is described in the H.460.19 standard.

Answer (score 1):

shark (packaged with wireshark) has this functionality built in.

Make sure that wireshark/tshark is in your PATH variable, and open a new command line window if you've just set it.  Let me know if you want me to be more clear there.

- If you want to discard the first 4 packets of rtp data on the fly :

  ```
  tcpdump -i eth0 port ! 5060 and dst 192.168.1.101 -T rtp -n -s0 -w- | editcap -F libpcap -C 4 - - | tcpdump -nlvvv -r - -w output.pcap
  ```
- For already captured file (capture.pcap):

  ```
  tcpdump -r capture.pcap | editcap -F libpcap -C 4 - - | tcpdump -nlvvv -r - -w output.pcap
  ```

or

```
editcap capture.pcap output.pcap -C 4
```

I didn't test these exact examples myself, but I think tshark's  "chop" (-C) option might be what you're looking for.